# how to print my array on desktop and replace by sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I write code that print names on desktop. If I click button it should replace with sorted names.
For example I have:

- Johny
- Amber
- Michael

And after press button should be replaced by:

- Amber
- Johny
- Michael

My code:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <script>
        var Tab = new Array('Johny', 'Amber', 'Michael')
        for (x=0; x<Tab.length; x++) { 
            w= "<li>" + Tab[x] + "</li>"
            document.write(w);
        }
        function myFunc(){
        var str = document.getElementById(w).value;
        var res = str.replace(w, Tab.sort());
        document.getElementById(w).innerHTML = res;
        }
    </script>
</ul>
</div>
<button type="button"  id="sort" onclick="myFunc()">Sort</button>
```

I have problem with myFunc().
How to replace/overwrite them?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` takes a string parameter, which should be the `id` of an element on your page. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can't just pass `w` to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write your list more than one time, then create a function for it. You will save time and code. I've called it `printTab`. To access the **ul** tag with JS, I've added an id to it: `list`. And now `myFunc`: let's just simply sort an array and print it again.

```
<div>
<ul id="list">
    <script>
        var Tab = new Array('Johny', 'Amber', 'Michael')

        function printTab() {
          var w = '';
          for (x=0; x<Tab.length; x++) { 
            w += "<li>" + Tab[x] + "</li>"
          }

          document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = w;
        }

        // we must be sure that DOM is loaded if we want to manipulate on it
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            printTab();
        });

        function myFunc(){
          Tab.sort();
          printTab();
        }
    </script>
</ul>
</div>
<button type="button"  id="sort" onclick="myFunc()">Sort</button>
```

My advice for you is to place scripts in a better place than inside some random tags, because it's making your HTML document chaotic and page load order pretty random. The best place for JS scripts is just before `</body>`.

Comment: thanks this is what I tried to do :) I promise give my voted when I get a reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the id of the div whose inner HTML you are modifying. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfp1ycyq/)

```
  <html>
  <div id="stuff">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="sort" onclick="myFunc()">Sort</button>

  <script>
    var Tab = new Array('Johny', 'Amber', 'Michael');

    function formList(Tab) {
      var w = "<ul>";
      for (x = 0; x < Tab.length; x++)
        w += "<li>" + Tab[x] + "</li>";
      w += "</ul>";
      return w;
    }

    document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = formList(Tab);

    function myFunc() {
      document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = formList(Tab.sort());
    }

  </script>

</html>
```